# NestJS: Cannot get nested object in console.log. Error: Property x does not exist on type Dto

Tags: javascript, typescript, controller, nestjs, dto

for some reason I cannot get the nested object to display in my console log. Been trying to look for a solution for about a day now.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
   "data": {
      "assets": [
              {
                 "asset_name": "Image1.jpg",
                 "asset_type": "photo",
                 "is_featured": true,
                 "asset_id": "alksjd78987120-kjahsdkjahsd61238-kjahsdkjahsjkdh",
                 "action": "delete"
              },
              {
                  "asset_name": "Image2.jpg",
                  "asset_type": "photo",
                  "action": "add"
              }
       ]
     }
   }
```

I am trying to display `console.log(data.assets);` in my controller file to check it before passing it to the service file but I keep on getting the error `Property 'assets' does not exist on type 'DataDto'.`

Here is my **DataDto.ts**

```
export class CreateAssetsDto {
   @IsString()
   @IsOptional()
   asset_id: string;

   @ApiProperty()
   @IsString()
   asset_name: string;

   @ApiProperty({
       enum: Action
   })
   @IsEnum(Action)
   @IsNotEmpty()
   action: Action;

   @ApiProperty()
   @IsString()
   asset_type: string;

   @ApiProperty()
   @IsBoolean()
   @IsOptional()
   is_featured: boolean;
}
export class AssetsArrayDto {
   @ValidateNested()
   @Type(() => CreateAssetsDto)
   assets: CreateAssetsDto[];
}

export class DataDto {
   @ValidateNested()
   @Type(() => AssetsArrayDto)
   data: AssetsArrayDto;
}
```

Here is my **controller.ts**

```
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
@Put(':id')
async uploadAssets(
   @Request() req,
   @Param('id') campaignId: string,
   @Body() data: DataDto) {
   try {
     console.log("Data Check");
     console.log(data);

     const { assets } = data;
     console.log(data.assets[0].asset_name);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

     const a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

     console.log(a)
     console.log(assets)

     return {
       statusCode: HttpStatus.OK,
       message: data,
     };

   } catch (error) {
     Logger.log('Validation Error: ');
     Logger.log(error);
     throw new BadRequestException(error);
   }
 }
 }
```

Do I need to do something that I missed? Based on the error it seems like my data object is not reading assets as part of it even though I indicated it in the DTO.

Also, when I do `console.log(data)`  this is what I get:

```
Data Check
DataDto {
 data: AssetsArrayDto { assets: [ [CreateAssetsDto], [CreateAssetsDto] ] }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've told Typescript that `DataDto` has a property called `data` that is of type `AssetsArrayDto`. You've told JavaScript to pull `assets` off of an instance of `DataDto`. `DataDto` does not have an `assets` property, so Typescript is warning you that what you're trying to do is incorrect. You'd need something like

```js
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
@Put(':id')
async uploadAssets(
   @Request() req,
   @Param('id') campaignId: string,
   @Body() data: DataDto) {
   try {
     console.log("Data Check");
     console.log(data);

     const { assets } = data.data;   // <-- notice the .data here
     console.log(data.assets[0].asset_name);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

     const a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

     console.log(a)
     console.log(assets)

     return {
       statusCode: HttpStatus.OK,
       message: data,
     };

   } catch (error) {
     Logger.log('Validation Error: ');
     Logger.log(error);
     throw new BadRequestException(error);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It was right in front of my eyes. You are a savior!!!!